# find out which country starts with certain character using R

Tags: r

i have a table country called gDat with column country, now i want to find out the country starts with Mal with this code

```
grep('Mal', levels(gDat$country))
```

but its returns only the id of that country (not the country name), how to solve this?

Comment: Lots of potential solutions for this, but one is to add the `value = TRUE` argument to `grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grepl` with the regex pattern `^Mal`:

```r
countries <- gDat$country[grepl("^Mal", gDat$country)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startsWith`

```
gDat$country[startsWith(gDat$country, "Mal")]
```

or `grep` with `value = TRUE`.

```
grep("^Mal", gDat$country, value = TRUE)
```